# Azure fluent management api bind custom root domain to app service

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I've been having trouble with this for a while and now I really need help.

This is the code I am currently using to bind a custom subdomain to Azure and everything is working just fine:

```
var appService = await azure.AppServices.WebApps.GetByIdAsync(
        "subscription-id");

await appService.Update().DefineHostnameBinding()
        .WithThirdPartyDomain("mydomain.net")
        .WithSubDomain("www")
        .WithDnsRecordType(CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName)
        .Attach()
        .ApplyAsync();
```

So what will be the way to bind just `mydomain.net` except that `CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName` should be changed with `CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.A` because Azure does not support `CNAME` records for root domains?
I cannot skip the `WithSubDomain(string)` method. Tried passing and null/empty string/space or just `.` but the response from Azure for null is Object reference not set to an instance and for the others is Bad Request.

P.S. I know that I am using an old SDK which is in maintenance mode but the new ones are still in beta or even alpha and there is still no support for App Services so I have to stick with that.

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [Can't attach CustomDomain to a web app](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/49), [Cannot bind custom domain](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/646) and [Have to add third party host name cname in a illogical way](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/1034)

Answer (score 0):

@DeepDave-MT pointed me to the correct answer in a comment under my question even though it's ridiculous. I am now quite sure I will go with this fluent API because there are too many things that are bothering me, almost no documentation, bad error handling and so on. Anyway, this is how to add a root domain in Azure using the so called fluent management API:

```
await appService.Update().DefineHostnameBinding()
    .WithThirdPartyDomain("mydomain.net")
    .WithSubDomain("@")
    .WithDnsRecordType(CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.A)
    .Attach()
    .ApplyAsync();
```

P.S. I don't know why I don't have the habit to check for issues in GitHub.